# getApplicationContext()' on a null object reference using volley in non-activity

Tags: android, json, android-volley

Take time trying to call a json from android, but the problem is the confusion of context, this is the error returned me

```
    02-09 19:48:05.494 16350-16350/com.example.cesar.mybankaccess E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
Process: com.example.cesar.mybankaccess, PID: 16350
java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'android.content.Context android.content.Context.getApplicationContext()' on a null object reference
at restful.dao.PatronSingleton.getRequestQueue(PatronSingleton.java:37)
at restful.dao.PatronSingleton.<init>(PatronSingleton.java:25)
at restful.dao.PatronSingleton.getInstance(PatronSingleton.java:30)
at restful.dao.Cliente.dologin(Cliente.java:84)
at restful.RestfulOperacional.dologin(RestfulOperacional.java:22)
at com.example.cesar.mybankaccess.view.Login.dologin(Login.java:118)
at com.example.cesar.mybankaccess.view.Login.access$100(Login.java:30)
at com.example.cesar.mybankaccess.view.Login$2.onClick(Login.java:67)
at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:5198)
at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:21147)
at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148)
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5417)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:726)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616)
```

I do not get fix, i'm sure is for context getContext or similar, but can't build one

```
public class RestfulOperacional {
    Cliente cliente;

    public RestfulOperacional() {
        cliente = new Cliente();
    }

    public Object dologin(String s, String s1) {
        return cliente.dologin(s, s1);
    }
}
```

And Class on try parse JSON

```
public class Cliente extends Application {
    private String URL_JSON;
    private static Context context;
    private static Cliente instance = null;

    public Cliente(Context context) {
        this.context = context;
    }

    public Cliente() {

    }


    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();
        context = getContext();
    }

    public static Context getContext() {
        return context;
    }
    public static Cliente getInstance(Context context) {
        if (instance == null) {
            instance = new Cliente(context);
        }
        return instance;
    }
    public Cliente dologin(String s, String s1) {
        URL_JSON = Constantes.URL_JSON + Constantes.URL_API_CLIENTE + Constantes.URL_API_CLIENTE_LOGIN;
        // Mapeo de los pares clave-valor
        HashMap<String, String> parametros = new HashMap();
        parametros.put("nif", s);
        parametros.put("claveSeguridad", s1);
        JsonObjectRequest jsArrayRequest = new JsonObjectRequest(
                Request.Method.POST,
                URL_JSON,
                new JSONObject(parametros),
                new Response.Listener<JSONObject>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onResponse(JSONObject response) {
                        Log.i("Json", response.toString());
                        // Manejo de la respuesta
                        //notifyDataSetChanged();
                    }
                },
                new Response.ErrorListener() {

                    @Override
                    public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                    }
                });
        PatronSingleton.getInstance(getContext()).addToRequestQueue(jsArrayRequest);
        return null;
    }
}
```

Comment: Which line causes the problem? Can you tell which reference is null?

Comment: i added all tracelog

Comment: Which line causes the problem?

Comment: PatronSingleton.getInstance(getContext()).addToRequestQueue(jsArrayRequest);

Comment: this is a weird way to use Application, you should move this networking logic elsewhere IMHO. it seems getContext() is always returning null since you have not actually set the context in your Cliente constructor call.

Comment: The line of code in your comment does not appear in the code you posted in your question. Also, it is too long. You are doing too many things in a single statement. You should break it up so that you can determine what part is returning a `null` reference.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You are setting context to null and getContext returns that value.

Try this

```
public class Cliente extends Application {

    protected static Cliente sInstance;
    private RequestQueue mRequestQueue;

    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();

        mRequestQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(this);
        sInstance = this;
    }

    public synchronized static Cliente getInstance() {
        return sInstance;
    }

    public RequestQueue getRequestQueue() {
        return mRequestQueue;
    }
}
```

Also, don't forget to add this `Application` to your Manifest like so in the application tag

```
<application
        android:name=".Cliente"
        android:allowBackup="true"
        ....
```

Alternatively, since `Application extends Context` in Android, you really don't need that variable... calling `getApplicationContext()` returns the Application object.

---

**Usage** -- move the Volley request to the Activity where you want to make the network connection in order to update the views and things in that class.

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private static String URL_JSON = "http://my.server.com/login";

    private ArrayAdapter<String> adapter;
    private ListView lv;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        // use android:id="@android:id/list" in ListView XML
        lv = (ListView) findViewById(android.R.id.list);

        // Simple adapter to show strings
        adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1);
        lv.setAdapter(adapter);

        doLogin("username?", "password?");
    }

    private void doLogin(String s, String s1) {

        HashMap<String, String> parametros = new HashMap<String, String>();
        parametros.put("nif", s);
        parametros.put("claveSeguridad", s1);

        JsonObjectRequest req = new JsonObjectRequest(
                Request.Method.POST,
                URL_JSON,
                new JSONObject(parametros),
                new Response.Listener<JSONObject>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onResponse(JSONObject response) {
                        Log.i("Json", response.toString());
                        // Manejo de la respuesta
                        adapter.add(response.toString());
                        adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                    }
                },
                new Response.ErrorListener() {

                    @Override
                    public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                        Log.e("Volley", error.getMessage());
                    }
                });

        // Start the request
        Cliente.getInstance().getRequestQueue().add(req);
    }

}
```

Comment: I just saw the update, but I have defined the following,     <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
        <activity
            android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name">

Comment: Add another application?

Comment: You need to add `android:name` under the application tag as shown

Comment: then if I want to add other Java classes that work like?

Comment: What do you mean? You can only have one class that extends Application. That class is shared throughout the app.

Comment: The problem, aside from getting json customer accounts also have to obtain and movements. However with this code I have enough, to solve my problem

Comment: I will make one more edit to show how to use the edits I just made