# How resolve multiple context in android:name tag? I'm using volley, json

Tags: android, json, rest, android-volley

Following this post reference

[getApplicationContext()' on a null object reference using volley in non-activity](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35300928/getapplicationcontext-on-a-null-object-reference-using-volley-in-non-activity)

This is my stage:

**Login** >(Call cliente) **Cliente.class**> Go to "**Welcome.class**"

**Movements** >(Call movements account) **Movimientos.class**> Return movements

**Accounts** > (Call list accounts) **Cuentas.class**> Return accounts

But I can only add to the AndroidManifest         **android:name="restful.dao.Cliente"**

```
<application
    android:name="restful.dao.Cliente"
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
```

All this using a URL volley and JSON.

Them, how can add property context for all non-activity?
 - Cliente.class 
 - Movimientos.class 
 - Cuentas.class

Considering, that I can not add more than one tag

- android:name="**restful.dao.Cliente**"
- android:name="**restful.dao.Movimientos**"
- android:name="**restful.dao.Cuentas**"

Answer (score 0):

You could pass `Context` as an argument to the non-activity class, and reference that instead of calling `getApplicationContext()`.

```
public class Cliente {
    private Context mContext;

    public Cliente(Context context) {
        mContext = context;

        // Now you can reference mContext 
        // instead of calling getApplicationContext()
    }
}
```

Now instanciate the `Cliente` class with `new Cliente(this);` or `new Cliente(getApplicationContext());` depending on where in your code you instanciates the `Cliente` class.

Comment: this only return null context

Answer (score 0):

You can only have one class that extends Application. Make it something like MyApp.

Then wherever you need context, get it from the calling activity, or from the MyApp instance.